# Merge complementary results inside a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I merge results inside a multidimensional array? For example, If I want to make a restaurant guide and crawl results from 2 sources and want to merge the complementary fields like this example (ratings) and keep both sources.

```
    Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                 [source] => Google 
                 [name] => Restaurant X
                 [lat] => -22.7
                 [lng] => -47.6
                 [google_rating] => 3
                 [facebook_rating] =>
           ) 
           [1] => Array ( 
                 [source] => Facebook 
                 [name] => Restaurant X
                 [lat] => -22.7
                 [lng] => -47.6
                 [google_rating] =>
                 [facebook_rating] => 4

           )
)
```

Expected result would be something like:

```
[0] => Array ( 
                 [source] => Google,Facebook
                 [name] => Restaurant X
                 [lat] => -22.7
                 [lng] => -47.6
                 [google_rating] => 3
                 [facebook_rating] => 4

           )
```